# How to pause Instagram story switching in console so I could download the image or video manually

Tags: javascript, console, instagram, webbrowser-control

I want to download an image or a video but I don't have enough time to find it in the inspector. Does anybody know how to stop all timers or particular function so I could paste it into the console and stop Instagram stories switching?

Answer (score 2):

The way is to pause all timers on the page.

```
// Set a fake timeout to get the highest timeout id
var highestTimeoutId = setTimeout(";");
for (var i = 0 ; i < highestTimeoutId ; i++) {
    clearTimeout(i); 
}
```

But timers will restart if you will switch the tab.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer pauses images in a story but it doesn't pause videos. I would combine the above code (which I think is clever) with this:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName("video").length){
    document.querySelector("video").pause();
}
// Set a fake timeout to get the highest timeout id
var highestTimeoutId = setTimeout(";");
for (var i = 0; i < highestTimeoutId; i++) {
    clearTimeout(i);
}
```